# how are optional inputs resolved when passed to a function in r

Tags: r

I'm working through the first example in R for data science and I see the following code:

```
ggplot(data=mpg) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=displ,y=hwy))
```

My understanding is that `mpg` is globally defined. The details here are a bit hazy.

Anyway, I can live with that. My real question is the next line. In particular, how in the heck `displ` and `hwy` are valid as used. If I run just the `aes` constructor call (constructor? function?) `displ` and `hwy` appear to be strings in the resulting output. In most other languages I would think this would cause an error because `displ` and `hwy` can't be resolved in the current workspace (e.g. `a=hwy` or in R `a<-hwy` would cause an error).

Does R have some behavior where any variable that looks like a string (i.e. `displ` but not `4.0` for example) that is not matched to a variable or function becomes a string in the called function/constructor when passed in, either via equals (as is the case here) or maybe even more generally as an input to a function???? What's going on?

Bonus: Is there a good resource for understanding this and any other quirks that may seem weird in R if you're used to other lanaguages?

Comment: This seems to be the "Non-standard evaluation" business. You make find the following link useful: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset

Comment: See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html

Comment: @Liman Correct, although your link points to an old version of the book. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: @Waldi, your link points to the new version of the book, which was confusing to say the least. Regardless, both you and Liman got me started in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently in R function inputs are only evaluated if they are accessed.

https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation

Hadley then goes on to define promises (not like a javascript promise), that normally will get evaluated once and replaced with the value. However, using magic, you can pull apart the components of the promise to do pretty much whatever you want, like in my example, storing those variables for use when accessing the dataframe, rather than trying to evaluate them based on normal scoping rules. This is all further explained in "metaprogramming" in the 2nd edition (as of this writing) in Hadley's Advanced R book:

https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html

Chapters 17 and 18 are warmups to Chapter 19, where the examples of this in action are clearly given. For example you can do (from the book):

```
f2 <- function(x) enexpr(x)
f2(a + b + c)
#> a + b + c
```

In that example, the function can retrieve the fact that the user passed in `a+b+c`, rather than just the result of a+b+c.

Interestingly, this is also how the non-string calls to `library` work:

```
library(tidyverse)
#same as
library("tidyverse")
```

`enexpr` is from rlang, a package that Hadley wrote, although there are similar functions in base R. Anyway, the details are a bit much for me at this point, the critical bit is that in R evaluation of arguments only occurs inside the function (when used), NOT before calling the function. The called function can then call special functions that allow you to pick apart this "promise", whereas normally the promise just gets evaluated to a value inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

R allows a ton of flexibility in evaluating arguments, and packages like `ggplot2` take advantage of it.  It is possible for a function to see the expression passed as an argument, and then to evaluate it in a special way.  `ggplot2` does this, so when `geom_point()` evaluates the expression `displ`, it does so in an environment that has the dataframe `mpg` attached ahead of everything else, and it finds the column there.